# Export data from 2 database in XML files

Tags: php, html, xml, database, export

First, I would apologize for my bad English, is pretty bad.

I come to you today for try to find a solution on my problem. I explain :

For my school project I need to do an inventory of PC come to us in my company and associated it with the sheet of the client. For that I have two database, one for the inventory and the other for the information of client (first name, last name and the name of his company).

So the connection on data base is good but I have some trouble for export my data from the two data base in a XML Files. I'm pretty bad for the moment in PHP and other internet language because I never practicing on it except now for my project.

So the code is :

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$client = $_POST['MagicCash'];
$pc = $_POST['fusioninventory'];

$nom = $bdd->query("SELECT nom FROM client WHERE IDClient= '.$client.'");
$prenom = $bdd->query("SELECT prenom FROM client WHERE IDClient= '.$client.'");
$societe= $bdd->query("SELECT societe FROM client WHERE IDClient='.$client.");
$CPU = $bdd->query("SELECT designation FROM glpi_deviceprocessors WHERE id= '.$pc.'");
$Archs = $bdd->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_plugin_fusioninventory_computerarchs WHERE id= '.$pc.'");
$DD = $bdd ->query("SELECT name, totalsize, freesize FROM glpi_computerdisks WHERE id= '.$pc.'");
$model = $bdd ->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_computermodels WHERE id= '.$pc.'");
$licence = $bdd->query("SELECT os_license_number, os_licenseid FROM glpi_computers WHERE id='.$pc.'");
$GPU = $bdd ->query("SELECT designation FROM glpi_devicegraphiccards WHERE id='.$pc.'");
$DD2 = $bdd ->query("SELECT designation FROM glpi_deviceharddrives WHERE id='.$pc.'");
$RAM = $bdd->query("SELECT designation, frequence FROM glpi_devicememories WHERE id='.$pc.'");
$OS = $bdd->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_operatingsystems WHERE id='.$pc.'");
$SP = $bdd->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_operatingsystemservicepacks WHERE id='.$pc.'");

/* create a dom document with encoding utf8 */
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("xml");

/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

$currentTrack = $domtree->createElement("inventaire");
$currentTrack = $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentTrack);

/* you should enclose the following two lines in a cicle */
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('nom',$nom));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('prenom',$prenom));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('societe',$societe));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('designation',$CPU));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$Archs));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name, totalsize, freesize',$DD));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$model));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('os_license_number, os_licenseid',$licence));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('designation',$GPU));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('designation',$DD2));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('designation',$RAM));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$OS));
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$SP));

/* get the xml printed */
echo $domtree->saveXML();
?>
```

And I have this error :

```
 Warning: DOMDocument::createElement() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php on line 34

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php on line 34
```

I let you my code of my HTML to :

```
include 'connection.php';

echo"<br>";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-AU" class="subpage"> 

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Projet</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="xmlv3.php" method="post">
        <label for="MagicCash">Client :</label>
            <select name="MagicCash" id="mc"> 
                <?php 
                    $id = array();
                    global $bdd;
                    $rep = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM client ORDER BY 'IDClient' DESC");
                    while ($tab = $rep->fetch()){
                        echo '<option name="client" value="'.$tab['IDClient'].'">'.$tab['IDClient'].' - '.$tab['Nom'].' '.$tab['Prenom'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        <label for="fusioninventory">PC :</label>
            <select name="fusioninventory" id="fi">
                <?php 
                    $id = array();
                    global $bdd1;
                    $rep = $bdd1->query("SELECT id,designation,frequence FROM glpi_deviceprocessors ORDER BY 'id' DESC");
                    while ($tab1 = $rep->fetch()){

                        echo '<option name="pc" value="'.$tab1['id'].'">'.$tab1['id'].' - '.$tab1['designation'].' '.$tab1['frequence'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Valider">
    </form>
</body>
```

Thx for you help in the futur.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, line 34 corresponds to :

```
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('nom',$nom));
```

From this line onwards you're passing values you read from the database to the createElement function. This function expects strings ans you passing and object read from the database to it. You can resolve this probably by doing any of these:

```
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('nom',(array)$nom['nom']));
or 
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('nom',$nom->nom));
```

This for all the statements from line 34 onwards

or you can maintain the code from line 34 and do something like this on your queries:

```
 $nom = $bdd->query("SELECT nom FROM client WHERE IDClient= '.$client.'")->fetchColumn();
$prenom = $bdd->query("SELECT prenom FROM client WHERE IDClient= '.$client.'")->fetchColumn();
$societe= $bdd->query("SELECT societe FROM client WHERE IDClient='.$client.")->fetchColumn();
$CPU = $bdd->query("SELECT designation FROM glpi_deviceprocessors WHERE id= '.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$Archs = $bdd->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_plugin_fusioninventory_computerarchs WHERE id= '.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$DD = $bdd ->query("SELECT name, totalsize FROM glpi_computerdisks WHERE id= '.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$model = $bdd ->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_computermodels WHERE id= '.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$licence = $bdd->query("SELECT os_license_number FROM glpi_computers WHERE id='.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$GPU = $bdd ->query("SELECT designation FROM glpi_devicegraphiccards WHERE id='.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$DD2 = $bdd ->query("SELECT designation FROM glpi_deviceharddrives WHERE id='.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$RAM = $bdd->query("SELECT designation, frequence FROM glpi_devicememories WHERE id='.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$OS = $bdd->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_operatingsystems WHERE id='.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
$SP = $bdd->query("SELECT name FROM glpi_operatingsystemservicepacks WHERE id='.$pc.'")->fetchColumn();
```

This will return a string and so you don't have to convert it anymore when creating the dom

Comment: Now I have some another error : Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$nom in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php on line 34
Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$prenom in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php on line 35
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php on line 36
Same for the line 37,38 and 39
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php:39 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php(39): DOMDocument->createElement('name, totalsize...', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php on line 39

Comment: which of the suggested solutions did u implement?

Comment: $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('nom',$nom->nom)); for all the lane between 34 and 46

Comment: I suggest you use my last suggestion

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_object() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlv3.php on line 7

Comment: I updated the answer, I was unaware you using pdo, try the code.  Let me know if it works.